# Проверка вхождения точки в сектор окружности (широта и долгота)

Tags: sql-server, геометрия, координаты

Знаю, что вопрос не новый, но у меня большие проблемы с реализацией, даже при успешном гуглении интересующих формул из-за того, что необходимо сопоставлять долготу и широту с радиусом заданным в метрах.

Есть два типа точек:

**Первый тип точек** являются центрами окружностей, у которых заданы интересующие сектора (на схеме показана одна точка **(X1,Y1)** у которой интересующий сектор задан синим цветом), **второй тип точек** это положение на местности некоторого объекта **(X2,Y2)**, для каждой отдельно взятой задачи этот объект будет всего **1**, но **каждый раз разный**.

Известен азимут сектора в градусах (на схеме это **Альфа** значения 0-360),

Радиус в метрах (на схеме **R**),

Ширина сектора в градусах (на схеме это **Бета** 0-360))

**Необходимо определить все точки, которые относятся к первому типу, в сектора которых попадает точка второго типа**

На первом этапе я отсек точки, которые не попадают в окружности описываемые координатами точек и радиусами секторов код на MS SQL, но решить задачу с секторами у меня не получается

```
DECLARE float @point_latitude = 57.2; DECLARE float @point_logitude = 65.5539; DECLARE int @max_radius = 1500
SELECT * FROM Test_table
WHERE 2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(RADIANS((@point_latitude-latitude)/2)),2)+COS(RADIANS(@point_latitude))*COS(RADIANS(latitude))*POWER(SIN(RADIANS((@point_logitude-longitude)/2)),2)))*6378245) <= @max_radius
```

[image: Пояснительная схема]

Comment: А можете уточнить, что значит "для каждой отдельно взятой задачи этот объект будет всего 1"? У вас есть конкретные пары сектор-точка или у вас именно список секторов и список точек?

Comment: У меня есть база, в которой хранятся данные о секторах (долгота, широта, азимут, радиус сектора, ширина сектора) и есть точка с координатами, надо найти все сектора в которые попадет точка ..

Comment: Можно считать, что сектора и точки заданы на плоскости, или вам нужно находить решение на сфере?

Comment: Можно считать, что они находятся на плоскости

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С sql-реализацией, я к сожалению, вам помочь не могу, но могу предложить реализацию на псевдокоде.

Пусть `Вектор(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)` - это вектор из точки 1 в точку 2. Он может быть определен как точка с координатами `(X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1)`.

Пусть `Угол(X1, Y1)` - это азимут вектора. Азимут у вас считается как угол по часовой стрелке от северного направления. Если север - это луч OY+, то на тригонометрической окружности он совпадает с точкой `pi/2`. Тогда азимут произвольного вектора можно вычислить как `(pi/2 - ATAN2(X1, Y1) + 2*pi) % (2*pi)`. Далее его нужно перевести в градусы по формуле `Угол_в_градусах = (Угол / 2pi) * 360`.

Теперь условием для нахождения сектора будет:

```
Выбрать все сектора такие, что 

(X2 - X1)^2 + (Y2 - Y1)^2 <= R1^2

И

Alpha1 - Beta1 / 2 <= Угол(Вектор(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)) <= Alpha1 + Beta1 / 2
```

Где `X1` и `Y1` - центр окружности; `X2` и `Y2` - точка; `R1` - радиус окружности; `Alpha1` - азимут сектора; `Beta1` - ширина сектора.

Upd: Спасибо MBo за дополнение. Может случиться такое, что `Alpha1 - Beta1 / 2 < 0` или `Alpha1 + Beta1 / 2 > 360`. Кажется это можно решить двумя дополнительными неравенствами, записав их к основному через ИЛИ: `Alpha1 - Beta1 / 2 + 360 <= Угол <= 360`, `0 <= Угол <= Alpha1 - Beta1 / 2 - 360`. Но это нужно протестировать, я не полностью уверен, что данные условия покрывают все крайние случаи.

Comment: На всякий случай - не забудьте проверить для Alpha = 10, Beta = 60, и точки под углом 350

Answer (score 0):

Наваял на Компонентном Паскале прототипчик. Два радара - (0,0) и (1,0), первый смотрит на Pi/4 с шириной охвата +/- pi/8, второй - на 3*Pi/4 с такой же широтой охвата. Радиус действия - 1.0. Мишени две - (0.5, 0.5) и (0.5, 0.5 + 0.1), - обе попадают в сектора обоих радаров.

Результат работы программы:

Target point  0 in sector of radar  0

Target point  1 in sector of radar  0

Target point  0 in sector of radar  1

Target point  1 in sector of radar  1

Исходник для BlackBox Component Builder:

```
MODULE DESLibSectors;

IMPORT M := Math, Log := StdLog;

TYPE
  Point = RECORD
    x, y : REAL;
  END;
  PropertyRadar = RECORD
    radius, directionAngle, widenessAngle : REAL;
  END;
  
  PointVector = POINTER TO ARRAY OF Point;
  RadarPropertiesVector = POINTER TO ARRAY OF PropertyRadar;

PROCEDURE Atan2 (x, y : REAL) : REAL;
  VAR
    result, pi, pi_2 : REAL;
  BEGIN
    pi := M.Pi();
    pi_2 := pi/2;
    IF x = 0 THEN
      IF y > 0.0 THEN
        RETURN pi_2;
      ELSIF y < 0.0 THEN
        RETURN  -pi_2;
      END;
    END;
    
    result := M.ArcTan (y/x); 
    IF x > 0 THEN
      RETURN result;
    ELSE
      IF y >= 0 THEN
        RETURN result + pi;
      ELSE
        RETURN result - pi;
      END; 
    END;
  END Atan2;

PROCEDURE IsPointInRadarSector (pointRadar, pointTarget : Point; radarProperty : PropertyRadar) : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    result : BOOLEAN;
    r, rx, ry, angle, angle_min, angle_max : REAL;
    normalized : Point;
  BEGIN
    rx := pointTarget.x - pointRadar.x;
    ry := pointTarget.y - pointRadar.y;
    r := M.Sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry);

    IF r = 0.0 THEN
      RETURN TRUE; (* если объект прямо на радаре - видимо он таки в секторе :) *)
    END;
    
    result := (r <= radarProperty.radius); (* дистанция меньше радиуса охвата радара *)

    angle_min := radarProperty.directionAngle - 0.5*radarProperty.widenessAngle;
    angle_max := radarProperty.directionAngle + 0.5*radarProperty.widenessAngle;

    normalized.x := rx/r; (* после нормализации - равен косинусу угла на мишень *)
    normalized.y := ry/r; (* после нормализации - равен синусу угла на мишень *)
    
    angle := Atan2 (normalized.x, normalized.y);
    result := result & (angle >= angle_min) & (angle <= angle_max); (* угол на мишень больше минимального угла радара и меньше максимального *)

    RETURN result;
  END IsPointInRadarSector;  
  
PROCEDURE TestPoints (pointsRadar, pointsTarget : PointVector; radarProperties : RadarPropertiesVector);
  VAR
    indRadar, indTarget : INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    FOR indRadar := 0 TO LEN (pointsRadar) - 1 DO
      FOR indTarget := 0 TO LEN (pointsTarget) - 1 DO
        IF IsPointInRadarSector (pointsRadar[indRadar], pointsTarget[indTarget], radarProperties[indRadar]) THEN
          Log.String ("Target point "); Log.Int (indTarget); Log.String (" in sector of radar "); Log.Int (indRadar); Log.Ln;
        END;
      END;
    END;
  END TestPoints;

PROCEDURE Run*;
  VAR
    numOfRadars, numOfTargets : INTEGER;
    pointsRadar, pointsTarget : PointVector;
    propertiesRadar : RadarPropertiesVector;
  BEGIN
    numOfRadars := 2;
    numOfTargets := 2;
    
    NEW (pointsRadar, 2);
    pointsRadar[0].x := 0.0;
    pointsRadar[0].y := 0.0;
    pointsRadar[1].x := 1.0;
    pointsRadar[1].y := 0.0;
  
    NEW (propertiesRadar, 2);
    propertiesRadar[0].radius := 1.0;
    propertiesRadar[0].directionAngle := M.Pi()/4;
    propertiesRadar[0].widenessAngle :=  M.Pi()/4;
    propertiesRadar[1].radius := 1.0;
    propertiesRadar[1].directionAngle := 3*M.Pi()/4;
    propertiesRadar[1].widenessAngle :=  M.Pi()/4;
    
    NEW (pointsTarget, 2);
    pointsTarget[0].x := 0.5;
    pointsTarget[0].y := 0.5;
    pointsTarget[1].x := 0.5;
    pointsTarget[1].y := 0.5 + 0.1;
    
    TestPoints (pointsRadar, pointsTarget, propertiesRadar);
  END Run;

END DESLibSectors.
```

DESLibSectors.Run

Answer (score 0):

Подход, который обрабатывает ситуации с переходом сектора через ноль автоматически, и не боится больших секторов:

Квадрат расстояния:

```
dx = X2-X1 
dy = Y2-Y1
r2 = dx^2 + dy^2
```

Если он меньше `R^2`, то продолжаем

```
r = sqrt(r2)
ux = dx / r
uy = dy / r
```

Теперь смотрим, что угол, образуемый вектором на точку, отклоняется от среднего азимута `alpha` менее, чем на `beta/2`. Для этого достаточно найти скалярное произведение единичного вектора в направлении `alpha` и единичного вектора на точку `ux, uy`, и сравнить его с косинусом `beta/2`

```
if ux * cos(alpha) + uy * sin(alpha) >= cos(beta/2)
    то точка внутри сектора
```